# How can I revert to the previous kernel version w/out dependency issues?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, dependencies

Since ubuntu updated my install to 3.2.0-37-generic, my laptop fan constantly runs. I never had this issue with the previous kernel versions. To fix this problem, I would like to revert back to the previous kernel version. Yet when I use grub and select one of the previous ones, I now have a red error display showing in the panel. the error message makes it sound like there is now some kind of dependency issue/s because I'm using the "old" kernel (it's only two versions back).

How can I revert back to using one of the older kernels and meet all dependencies (not have an error message)?

I'm using fully up to date 12.04.

```
E:Could not open file /var/lib/synaptic/preferences - open (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-3.2.0-37-generic`. Then reboot and it should work.

As fir the dependencies problem, you need to run synaptic as sudo.